# Explain carefully why the equation $3x=2$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My proof is below, but I am not sure if this is "carefully" enough. I am sure there are many better proofs out there, but this is the one that came to my mind first. Does this work?

Let us assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $3x=2$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$. This would then imply that $x$ is an element in $Z$, the set of integers. We can calculate $x$ as follows: $3x=2\Rightarrow \frac{3x}{3}=\frac{2}{3}\Rightarrow x=\frac{2}{3}$. Any integer can be written as the fraction $z=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers and, importantly, $a=n\cdot b$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. This means the numerator must be a multiple of the denominator. There are infinitely many different possibilities for $a,b$ for any $z\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, it is impossible for this to be true for $\frac{2}{3}$ as the numerator must be strictly less than the denominator. Therefore we have reached a contradiction and $3x=2$ can not have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I really don't think $\frac{2}{3}$ not being an integer is something that needs to be proved.

Comment: The numerator being less than the denominator does not seem to be super rigorous as written. The number $-4/2$ has a numerator which is less than the denominator but is still an integer.

Comment: @Mark It said carefully, so I figured I should prove that. Do you think I am going overboard?

Comment: @Matt duh, thank you. Didn't consider negative numerators. I can't really think of another proof for how n can not be an integer. Perhaps I was going about this the wrong way. Maybe I should mention the absolute value of the numerator?

Comment: I suspect they actually wish you to say something to the lines of:  If $3x = 2$ had an integer solution then $2$ would be a multiple of $3$. But it is not as $2$ is prime.  I *really* don't think they are asking for more than that.  But to be sure can you quote the *exact* question as it was asked.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question without context.  What *else* were you proving and explaining around the time.

Comment: I don't think the context helps much which is why I didn't include it. The full problem is [here](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/5b964142-fa75-49b2-aca1-15f60172140c.png). It is just a beginning analysis class.

Comment: By "context" I meant, what are you learning in you classes?  How were the integers defined.  How were solving equations approached?  Have prime numbers been introduced?

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: @fleablood the book is Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus by Kenneth Ross. The set of natural numbers was defined as a set with the element 1, a set where n is in the set, then n+1 is also in the set. Also, 1 is not the successor for any element in the set. We mentioned primes in some problems, but they have not been formally defined.

Comment: Looking at the text, I'd say with almost certainty saying $2$ is not a multiple of $3$ is enough.  But perhaps you should talk to your instructor.

Comment: @fleablood yes, I will clarify tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alt. hint (without division or rational numbers): $\;x = 0\,$ is obviously not a solution, so $\,|x| \ge 1\,$. But then $\,|3x| = 3 |x| \ge 3 \gt 2 = |2|\,$ so the equality $\,|3x|=|2|\,$ cannot hold, and neither can $\,3x=2\,$.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be very surprised if you must prove that $\frac 23$ is not an integer.

However $3 > 0$ so $a < b \iff 3a < 3b$ and in particular $0 < \frac 23 < 1 \iff 0*3 < \frac 23*3 < 1*3 \iff 0 < 2 <3$.

And as it is true that $0 < 2 < 3$ it must be true that $0 < \frac 23 < 1$.  And there is no such integer.